# Что еще добавить в функцию фильтрации опасностей?

Tags: php, безопасность

Есть функция которая чистит данные от пользователя перед записью в БД. Чем ее еще дополнить можно чтобы сделать безопасность выше.

В некоторых полях есть визуальный редактор, функция должна пропускать теги, но только безопасные.

```
public function checkrequest($textrequest) {
    // Удираем лишние пробелы
    $textrequest = trim($textrequest);
    // Производим конвертацию в необходимую кодировку (нужно если у Вас проект использует кодировку отличную от UTF-8)
    //$textrequest = iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1251", $textrequest);

    // Фиксируем атаки
    if (preg_match("/script|SELECT|UNION|UPDATE|.exe|.exec|INSERT|tmp/i",$textrequest)) {
        $textrequest = '';
    }  

    return $textrequest;                        
}
```

**Что дописать посоветуете?**

Comment: Посоветую не заниматься тратой времени, а просто не конкатенировать эту строку в SQL запросы и на html страницу выводить только с экранированием

Comment: @AntonShchyrov  если не сложно показать как правильно на моем примере?

Comment: У Вас нет никакого примера. У Вас есть фильтрация, я сказал, что она не нужна совсем. Больше я Вашего кода не вижу